# Setting a Google Form to refresh on submission

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Have google form on website in HTML.

The problem I have is that on submission the user is redirected to ugly confirmation page.

The form is designed to receive multiple submissions.

My solution is to make page refresh when form is submitted, allowing the entry to be sent and having the page ready for a new one in one click.

However I cannot get this to work.

I've tried wrapping the submit button in anchor tag

> ```
> <a href="javascript:history.go(0)"> 
>    <button type="submit"> SUBMIT </button>
> </a>
> ```

I've tried giving two values to submit button

> ```
> <input type="button" class="sbutton" name="submit" type="submit"    
> value="Submit" value="Refresh Page"
> onClick="window.location.reload()"/>
> ```

I've tried to link to the webpage without first knowing its name

> ```
> <a href="?"> 
>    <button type="submit"> SUBMIT </button> 
> </a>
> ```

As you can see, I'm lost. Any help much appreciated.

Here is the script I'm using to submit the form, none of the solutions so far have been able to do what I specified, because they seem to clash in some way with the following:

```
<script>
$('#input-form').one('submit',function(){
    var inputq1 = encodeURIComponent($('#input-q1').val());
    var inputq2 = encodeURIComponent($('#input-q2').val());
    var inputq3 = encodeURIComponent($('#input-q3').val());
    var q1ID = "entry.340878806";
    var q2ID = "entry.569569223";
    var q3ID = "entry.1623478195";
    var baseURL = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSf6So7J-     dJum3X4_rWAn07yALmyirzHDvufr5Ke3FUTXuR5wA/formResponse?';
    var submitRef = '&submit=1480224357040003724';
    var submitURL = (baseURL + q1ID + "=" + inputq1 + "&" + q2ID + "=" + inputq2 + "&" + q3ID + "=" + inputq3 + submitRef);
    console.log(submitURL);
    $(this)[0].action=submitURL;
    $('#input-feedback').text('Word succesfully submitted, refresh page to submit a new one');
        });
```

Comment: Provide more details about your form ... ?

Comment: what do you want to know?

   ' <form id="input-form" action="" method="POST" target="no-target" autocomplete="off">

     <input id="input-q1" placeholder="word" name="q1" type=text>

      <input id="input-q2" placeholder="translation" name="q2" type=text>

      <input id="input-q3" placeholder="memory" name="q3" type=text>

      <button id="form-submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form> '

Then I have a <script> </script> function triggered when submit button is clicked.

Comment: please see the post, I have added the relevant script to help explain what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your form, I'm assuming that you're trying to refresh the page to get rid of the submitted page. Why take the user to that page in the first place? You can do that with the following:

```
onclick="SubmitForm(); return false;"
```

To clear the form after returning from the submitted page, add the following line in your submit function:

```
function SubmitForm() {
   document.formName.reset(); 
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to reset the page so the user can put a new submission in the form, there is no redirect to a submit page. (if I understand your comment correctly)

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion and it didn't work? I think I understand what you're looking for and provided what I have to provide.

Comment: I've avoided the whole need for a submission page through the script I've written. So the form is submitted on the same page it's entered. So rather than avoid any submission page, I'm trying to reset the same page after submission. Going to try to implement your code now, thank you.

Comment: implementing the first one leaves the fields filled, I need them to reset.

implementing the second one leads to the same outcome.

Comment: I modifed the post to add the current script at the bottom. Adding your code stops the form from submitting properly for some reason.